# Do I need to pay the package transmission fee (Canadian visa)?

Tags: visas, canada, standard-visitor-visas, fees-and-charges

I submitted biometrics at a Canadian ASC (not VAC) in the US and I received a letter asking me to submit the passport to a VAC. (In particular, I paid a biometrics fee of 85 CAD)

[This page](https://www.vfsglobal.ca/Canada/USA/how_to_apply.html#temporary_documents) says to include a money order in the envelope with the passport:

[image]

But it also says that the package transmission fee is a subset of fees required for those who are **not** enrolling in biometrics. However since I've given my biometrics, I guess I **am** enrolling in biometrics. Do I need to enclose the money order then?

[Here is another source:](https://www.vfsglobal.ca/Canada/usa/Service_and_Service_Charge.html)

> Applicants who submit their passport or documents at a different VAC from the one where they initially provided biometrics, Package Transmission fees will apply.
>
> If no package is transmitted at the time of biometric enrolment (when the application has been submitted online), the initial package transmission is included in the fee of CAD $85 for biometric enrolment and package transmission.

According to the first sentence, I do need to pay the transmission fee.

According to the second, I don't.

So I'm not sure if I actually need to pay this fee.

Comment: Can the transmission fees be paid by personal check instead of money order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is "yes".

[image]